# .htaccess rewrite based on referrer

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'd like to direct all traffic coming from a particular domain (`foo.net`) to the homepage of my website (`http://www.bar.net/index.php`). I've tried many, many ways of doing this, some of which crash the site, others of which simply don't work. However, I can now reliably get it to direct to `google.com` or `bbc.com` using the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?foo\.net
  RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bbc.com [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the current code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?foo\.net
  RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bar.net/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, nearly all the traffic comes via one link to a particular page on my site `http://www.bar.net/?q=en/tickets` and when I redirect to my own homepage, `?q=en/tickets` is always appended to the URL and the visitor is sent to the tickets page anyway (the URL looks like this: `http://www.bar.net/index.php?q=en/tickets`

It's a Drupal site so the `.htaccess` has other content, and I've put this right at the beginning of the `.htaccess`. I feel I just need to tweak something here - any ideas

Answer (score 2):

Add a `?` to the end of target URL:

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bar.net/index.php? [L]
```

or use `[QSD]` flag if you're on apache 2.4

```
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.bar.net/index.php [L,QSD]
```

Comment: Perfect - worked like a charm. Knew it would be something basic like that. Thanks for your help!